# Subtraction, what find the product of 2 and 9 means, then take that by 3 means?

Tags: meaning

> Find the product of 2 and 9 and then take that from three.

I'm confused. What does that mean?

Comment: Is it **by** three or **from** three?  Your subject and question say different things.

Answer (score 9):

"The product of X and Y" means X × Y (X multiplied by Y).

"Take X from Y" means Y − X (subtract X from Y)

So: 3 − (2 × 9) = −15

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how it is written because to me '&' is not a mathematical symbol.

> **If** you mean 2 times 9 = , then that answer is X. Take X from 3? 3-X= Y

I am not going to do the multiplication and subtraction for you.

the question was edited!